# Shell extension or similar to force delete files

Tags: windows, ntfs

Is there a shell extension or something that allows me to delete files from Explorer, even if it has to take ownership and adjust the permissions of the files first?

Answer (score 1):

[Take Ownership](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/download/did/3557/) is a Registry file that adds an Explorer context-menu item to change ownership of a file.

For some other tools, and a *caveat*, see [6 Tools To Take Ownership and Get Full Control Of Files and Folders](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/easily-take-ownership-and-grant-full-control-permission-with-winownership/).

CrystalRich [LockHunter](https://lockhunter.com/) will unlock or delete files locked by a process, though it won't change ownership.

**N.B.** There is the potential to create havoc in the OS that may make a system completely unusable. Also, check any downloaded utility at VirusTotal.com.

Comment: A very good answer! I wasn't aware of take OWnership, but can't recommend LockHunter enough - a "must have" tool for everyone.